# Calculation hours a week

Tags: excel

I am looking for a formula to calculate hours a week according to a column.

For example, I have 5 rows "week 1", 5 rows "week 2" and 5 rows "week3" with for each hours a day. I'd like to have the sum of hours a week for each week.

Do you have some ideas ?

[Here is a google sheets link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19EAs3Fv9FwtaQXMk0iIXlrwaCRsSKoSNcHEFHfLRM0I/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Can you please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/24659478) to include sample data? otherwise it will be useless once that link goes dead. That said, looks like you are maybe looking for `SUMIF`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C2 put:

```
=IF(A2<>A3,SUMIF(A:A,A2,B:B),"")
```

And copy down

[image]

---

The above assumes that the weeks are grouped together, If they are not then use:

```
 =IF(A2<>A3,SUM($B$2:$B2)-SUM($C$1:$C1),"")
```

Which will only total by groups.

Comment: @lfilleur I see in your Google document that you are trying to apply Scott's solution but it returns an error. First of all, replace all `,` with `;`, just like that: `=IF(A2<>A3;SUMIF(A:A;A2;B:B);"")`. Also, paste this formula into cell `C2` and drag it down (currently you have this formula in cell `C6`, which is incorrect - it actually should be `=IF(A6<>A7;SUMIF(A:A;A6;B:B);"")`. Hope it solves your issues.